# Istio MultiCluster Network Policy

Tags: security, networking, kubernetes, devops, istio

I have an ISTIO on my two kubernetes clusters as a replicated control plane. In my case, some networking policies that restricting labeled deployment object access , but these are working on the only one cluster .

How I can implement domain and service restriction between two clusters on Istio ? Have you got any suggestion ?

Thanks

Sample Network Policy :

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: policy-new
  namespace: point-1
spec:
  ingress:
  - from:
    - podSelector:
        matchLabels:
          run: app2
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      run: app
```

Answer (score 0):

Kubernetes [`NetworkPolicy`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/) might have limited use for multicluster.

It is better to use Istio's [`AuthorizationPolicy`](https://istio.io/docs/concepts/security/#authorization-policy). According to istio documentation:

> To configure an Istio authorization policy, you create an  [`AuthorizationPolicy`  resource](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/security/authorization-policy/).
>
> An authorization policy includes a selector and a list of rules. The selector specifies the  **target**  that the policy applies to, while the rules specify  **who**  is allowed to do  **what**  under which  **conditions**. Specifically:
>
> - **target**  refers to the  `selector`  section in the  `AuthorizationPolicy`.
> - **who**  refers to the  `from`  section in the  `rule`  of the  `AuthorizationPolicy`.
> - **what**  refers to the  `to`  section in the  `rule`  of the  `AuthorizationPolicy`.
> - **conditions**  refers to the  `when`  section in the  `rule`  of the  `AuthorizationPolicy`.
>
> Each rule has the following standard fields:
>
> - **`from`**: A list of sources.
> - **`to`**: A list of operations.
> - **`when`**: A list of custom conditions.
>
> The following example shows an  `AuthorizationPolicy`  that allows two sources (service account  `cluster.local/ns/default/sa/sleep`  and namespace  `dev`) to access the workloads with labels  `app: httpbin`  and  `version: v1`  in namespace foo when the request is sent with a valid JWT token.

```
apiVersion: security.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: AuthorizationPolicy
metadata:
 name: httpbin
 namespace: foo
spec:
 selector:
   matchLabels:
     app: httpbin
     version: v1
 rules:
 - from:
   - source:
       principals: ["cluster.local/ns/default/sa/sleep"]
   - source:
       namespaces: ["dev"]
   to:
   - operation:
       methods: ["GET"]
   when:
   - key: request.auth.claims[iss]
     values: ["https://accounts.google.com"]
```

---

Also I recommend reading [this](https://istio.io/blog/2020/multi-cluster-mesh-automation/) and [this](https://istio.io/blog/2019/isolated-clusters/) istio blog posts which cover topics of multicluster security and about [Admiral](https://github.com/istio-ecosystem/admiral) an open source project under istio-ecosystem that provides automatic configuration generation, syncing and service discovery for multicluster Istio service mesh.

Ambassador can be configured to lock down communication except for the traffic which WE specify with use of `ServiceEntry`, `Dependency` and `GlobalTrafficPolicy` objects.

Hope this helps.